# Win32 cmd dir /q, but list group SID for the file?

Tags: winapi, cmd

How can I get the group SID for a file in cmd.exe (powershell is not an option)?

Comment: [`RtlGetGroupSecurityDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlgetgroupsecuritydescriptor)  or `GetSecurityDescriptorGroup` after you call `GetKernelObjectSecurity` with `GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION`

Comment: Obtain the file_sid of the file by`getfilesecurity`, get the ower_sid/group_sid by `GetSecurityDescriptorOwner/GetSecurityDescriptorGroup`, call `LookupAccountSid` to get the ower/group name.

Answer (score 1):

i not sure that you can do this with cmd, but because and until you tag this as **winapi** i show solution by use this.

```
NTSTATUS PrintFileGroup(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    NTSTATUS status;
    if (0 <= (status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, READ_CONTROL, poa, &iosb, 0, 0)))
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
        };
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x100;
        PVOID stack = (PVOID)alloca(guz);
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                // /RTCs must not be set
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }
            status = NtQuerySecurityObject(hFile, GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD, cb, &rcb);
        } while (STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL == status);

        NtClose(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            PSID Group;
            BOOLEAN b;
            if (0 <= (status = RtlGetGroupSecurityDescriptor (pSD, &Group, &b)))
            {
                UNICODE_STRING str;
                if (0 <= RtlConvertSidToUnicodeString(&str, Group, TRUE))
                {
                    DbgPrint("G=%wZ\n", str);
                    RtlFreeUnicodeString(&str);
                }

                LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa) };
                HANDLE hPolicy;
                if (0 <= (status = LsaOpenPolicy(0, &oa, POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES, &hPolicy)))
                {
                    PLSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST ReferencedDomains = 0;
                    PLSA_TRANSLATED_NAME Names = 0;
                    if (0 <= (status = LsaLookupSids2(hPolicy, 0, 1, &Group, &ReferencedDomains, &Names)))
                    {
                        ULONG DomainIndex = Names->DomainIndex;
                        PCUNICODE_STRING DomainName = 0;
                        if (DomainIndex < ReferencedDomains->Entries)
                        {
                            DomainName = &ReferencedDomains->Domains[DomainIndex].Name;
                        }

                        DbgPrint("%x %wZ\\%wZ\n", Names->Use, DomainName, &Names->Name);
                    }
                    LsaFreeMemory(ReferencedDomains);
                    LsaFreeMemory(Names);
                    LsaClose(hPolicy);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

say for `\??\c:`
i got

```
G=S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464
5 NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
```